# HQL left outer join :Path expected for join

Tags: hql

SELECT a.cell_field_name,b.lang_text_value,a.cell_template,a.cell_visible,a.cell_widthFROM sys_grid_properties as a left join 
sys_langs as b on
a.lang_menu_code = b.lang_menu_code and 
a.cell_display_name = b.lang_text_code

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Format the HQL properly. Why is there no space before the "FROM" command?